# How to use MySQL to query on json array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, search

I have a table as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `tb_test` (`id`, `content`) VALUES (1, '[{"name": "vabcx", "value": 100}, {"name": "uabcw", "value": 150}, {"name": "xxx", "value": 110}]');
INSERT INTO `tb_test` (`id`, `content`) VALUES (2, '[{"name": "jabcl", "value": 130}, {"name": "xabcf", "value": 150}, {"name": "uuu", "value": 110}]');
INSERT INTO `tb_test` (`id`, `content`) VALUES (3, '[{"name": "pabcg", "value": 100}, {"name": "qabct", "value": 100}, {"name": "hhh", "value": 300}]');
```

And I have two requirements:

1. Find the rows whose name contains "abc" and the value of all names containing "abc" is greater than 120. i.e., for the above table, select the rows with id=2.
2. Find the rows whose name contains "abc" and at least one of the names containing "abc" has a value greater than 120. i.e., for the above table, select the rows with id=1 and id=2.

I tried the following sql, but all 3 rows are selected because name and value are handled separately.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE content->'$**.name' LIKE '%abc%'and content->'$**.value' > 120;
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | content                                                                                           |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"name": "vabcx", "value": 100}, {"name": "uabcw", "value": 150}, {"name": "xxx", "value": 110}] |
|  2 | [{"name": "jabcl", "value": 130}, {"name": "xabcf", "value": 150}, {"name": "uuu", "value": 110}] |
|  3 | [{"name": "pabcg", "value": 100}, {"name": "qabct", "value": 100}, {"name": "hhh", "value": 300}] |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In adderation, for requirement 2, I don't want to use the following sql because there may be $[4], $[5]...... in the future.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE content->'$[0].name' LIKE '%abc%'AND content->'$[0].value' > 120 OR content->'$[1].name' LIKE '%abc%'AND content->'$[1].value' > 120 OR content->'$[2].name' LIKE '%abc%'AND content->'$[2].value' > 120;
```

I also know that storing the content as the table below will solve the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_test01` (
  `ass_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'associated ID',
  `name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

But I want to know how to use sql and json, or any other good way to solve my problem.

I've learned some json search functions from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html).

I'm looking forward to your help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON_TABLE to get the name/value pairs into rows and columns:

```
select id, j.* from tb_test cross join json_table(content, '$[*]' columns (
  name varchar(20) path '$.name', 
  value int path '$.value')) as j;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | value |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | vabcx |   100 |
|  1 | uabcw |   150 |
|  1 | xxx   |   110 |
|  2 | jabcl |   130 |
|  2 | xabcf |   150 |
|  2 | uuu   |   110 |
|  3 | pabcg |   100 |
|  3 | qabct |   100 |
|  3 | hhh   |   300 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Then you can use a `WHERE` clause to select the rows you want.

Comment: The JSON is an array, and the object position may be nesessary, so it may be safe to add `rowno FOR ORDINALITY` as demonstration.

Comment: It is a worthwhile idea and I will verify its feasibility with large-scale data, thank you very much.